# How does citrus juicer randomly change its direction?

Tags: motor

I dismantled my electric citrus juicer and wanted to understand how the simple motor, coil and wiring could make the juicer switch its rotation direction randomly, each time the shaft is pressed.

I'm talking about this kind of model: [Citrus Juicer Inside 1](https://free3d.com/3d-model/citrus-juicer-inside-1-7314.html)

Comment: whatever direction it starts in it will keep going. It starts in the direction of where the magnets and the shaft are closest, which depends on where it lands the last time it ran and stopped, which is pretty random. Think of it like a clock hand stopping; from 1:00-1:29: counter-clockwise, 1:30-1:59: clockwise.

Comment: agenis, You can read about [single phase motors](https://www.thomasnet.com/articles/machinery-tools-supplies/single-phase-industrial-motors-how-do-they-work/) and how they operate. (Not randomly!) If it didn't start randomly before you dismantled the contraption, and is doing so now, you may also have removed a useful part (like the start capacitor) or otherwise removed the start winding from the equation.

Comment: thanks @dandavis very useful, i guess that answers my question. thanks periblepsis for pointing out the type of motor, i did not know this.

Answer (score 2):

Single phase synchronous motors may start and run in either direction.

They can also be physically forced to change direction.

When they are used in timers there is often an anti-reversing mechanism that jams the motor to force it to run in the correct direction.